# Losing internet connection BUT can connect to other computers on LAN

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

... and other computers on LAN have connection to internet.

Connecting via a WiFi extender to ISP provided router.

I can ssh to a computer that is hard wired to the router and show that that has a working internet connection (via the router).

Restarting network-manager does not help.

Restarting Ubuntu (without restarting the router or extender) always solves the problem.

Using Ubuntu 16.04. A way to restart whatever is stopping without having to restart the whole PC would help.

Comment: probably `dhcpd` ?

Comment: Thanks @damadam but I don't _think_ I'm using dhcpd(?). It's not a running process and isn't a recognised service ...

Comment: made a mistake typo, `udhcpd` is the name

Comment: The only process with *dhc* in the name is /sbin/dhclient and I've just checked and that is restarted when I restart network-manager.

Comment: When u ssh into your lan-pc's do you use ip adresses? ever tried to `ping google.com` and `ping 172.217.18.14` ? If both is not working, i dont know. If IP is working than it might be a DNS issue. Compare the output of `route` before you reboot while internet is not working, with the output of `route` after you did reboot while the internet is working. Any differences? The same you could do with the outputs of `cat /etc/resolver.conf`

Comment: Good point. The lan-pc's ip address is in /etc/hosts. I'll try pinging google directly next time it goes down ... which of course it's stopped doing!!!